# Was there a time-lapse element to Otherland?

Tags: otherland

In the [*Otherland*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otherland) novels, the protagonists enter a Virtual Reality environment for an extended time to investigate an enormous network, and are locked into it.

I've read the books several times, and thoroughly enjoy each, but I am curious if, within the story of the mental fabric, there was a time-difference due to the hypnotic nature of the way it intruded on brain stimuli – sort of like how a dream goes by.

**Is there any indication in the novels or from the author that there is anything other than an internal time = clock time** arrangement?

Comment: There wasn't any internal reference point in Otherland for time.  While it's certainly possible, and there's plenty of evidence that characters lose time when the... "OS"... gets too intrusive, most of the hypnotic suggestion was to convince the brain that it was all real, without which it was very clearly just a simulation, albeit the best one ever built.

Comment: @Radhil - thanks; I was trying to suss out the gaps between what was happening in real life vs what was happening during the virtual reality: it's a remarkable story, so I'd like to reconcile the time differences even if it doesn't amount to anything to anyone else.

Answer (score 2):

No, the passage of time within Otherland seems to basically match real world time. That's why some of the characters had to make extensive preparations to stay in VR for an extended duration safely. Days or weeks spent investigating in Otherland would require just as long IRL and with no ability to log out for rest, food, etc. There's also several characters who are able to make contact from outside into Otherland, such as Orlando's robot AI assistant, and from what I recall the cadence of those interactions matches the idea that subjective time in Otherland matches subjective time IRL. At least for the actual human beings logged into the system.

> The big exception to this in the main cast is Paul Jonas who is not an actual human being connected to the system but is actually an AI replica of the real Paul Jonas. From what I recall his segments, especially early on, are the most trippy dream sequence types where the progression of time is uncertain. Presumably as an AI being run by the system his subjective experience of time is not bound to a physical human brain like everyone else.

Comment: Also, the mystery of all the catatonic people (who turned out to be locked in the game) was a big driver of the early story.

Comment: I believe PJ did gain a memory of his real life, though, no?  (I was going to elaborate in this comment, but I don't know how to do a spoiler in comments)